# How would a creature made by Mad Science malfunction?

Tags: deadlands-d20

If I recall correctly, Deadlands mad science can allow for the creation/augmentation of living things, but most examples given for Malfuctions (i.e. when they happen or what happens) are just for mechanical creations. Is there any precedent in the rules for any such thing, or am I just to assume that when my lobotomized Hawkoyote rolls a 1 to do anything he suffers a grand-mal seizure instead?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily... I would advice sitting down with your Marshal and explaining this concern, and tell him that this is one of those times the book tells him to be vindictive. Half the fun of being a mad scientist is watching your inventions betray you. Perhaps on each malfunction, Hawkoyote should have to draw a card from the deck, and on a joker it becomes possessed. Perhaps it swallows a demon on every malfunction, slowly collecting a whole bellyful of hell's fury ready to be released the next time he's opened up to be worked on, or dies.